Creating a Wireless Topology with Mininet Wifi
I am trying to create this topology in mininet-wifi.
The main idea I am trying to apply is to create a redundant links between every station in the network. For example, I want to be able to connect sta1 to sta4 through both ap1-ap4 and ap1-ap2-ap3-ap4 for example.
My question is: How to create this redundancy without interference? I tried to create a mesh network between all 4, but when I start an iperf flow from sta4 to sta1, and then sta2 to sta3, they interfere each other!
In other words, how to create a ethernet-like link between each node in the setup, that doesn't interfere with other links?
I think I am limited to these options.
 iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A 10
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * outside context of a BSS

I can't post images so I'll try to draw it.
ap1 --- ap2
|        |
|        |
|        |
ap3 ---- ap4

And there is one station connected to each AP

You can only avoid interference by… avoiding interference: Not using overlapping channels. That means having as many radios as links – on each device.

Wi-Fi access points interconnect using Ethernet – and to have two connections like this you pretty much need an Ethernet switch involved, as purely an AP has just a "Wi-Fi side" and "Ethernet side" – so it's really an Ethernet question, not so much a Wi-Fi question.
If you have a ring or some other kind of loop, when it comes to regular Ethernet switches or bridges, you need to run a version of STP (generally RSTP/MSTP preferred) between all of the bridges to prune loops. Unfortunately, it does not allow for different flows taking different paths – it will keep one link blocked until it's needed, e.g. blocking ap3--ap4 and letting traffic go ap3--ap1--ap2--ap4 instead.
Very high-end Ethernet switches might have smarter protocols for Ethernet routing (e.g. SPB, TRILL, or the various proprietary ring Ethernet protocols) that would be able to choose a shortest path per-destination, but that seems to be very rare.
I think Linux supports the standard Wi-Fi mesh routing protocol (HWMP aka 802.11s) for access points in mesh point mode, but only between wireless links, not between Ethernet-wired APs, if I understand it correctly.
Linux does support another Ethernet mesh routing protocol, B.A.T.M.A.N, which you can run on the eth* interfaces (creating a virtual bat0) and then bridge your APs to bat0 instead of bridging the Ethernet ports directly. Non-kernel methods such as bridging the AP to a virtual ZeroTier interface would also work.
IP-layer routing has many more choices (e.g. OSPF or Babel) but since it needs each AP to have its own IP subnet, that would prevent AP roaming and require unique SSIDs for each AP, so it's probably not an option.

Hi @grawity_u1686. Thanks for your reply!
I didn't talk about flow rerouting because I am using SDN (ONOS controller). It always forward the traffic through the shortest path on L2 and L3.
So, I am only asking about connections here. How to connect these APs in a point-point connection style, without interference. Mesh didn't work for me.
